# sending a file with axios, without FormData api

Tags: javascript, ajax, axios, multipartform-data

I can send a file to the server using axios and the FormData api, like that :

```
    persist(avatar){
        let data = new FormData();
        data.append('avatar', avatar);
        axios.post(`/api/users/${this.user.name}/avatar`, data)
            .then(() => flash('Avatar uploaded!'));
    }
```

The avatar param, passed to persist(), is a file object from a form input of type "file".

I can then grab the file on the server side.

Is it possible to do it without using FormData ?  That is, to simulate the FormData work ?   Basically, I'm trying to understand the extra work done by the FormData api. Maybe it's not possible using axios, and I should do that with plain XMLHttpRequest.

Of course, simply sending the file object won't work :

```
axios.post(`/api/users/${this.user.name}/avatar`, {avatar: avatar})
```

On the server side, the avatar object will be empty. I can send metadata like avatar.name, but not the whole object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to do the encoding manually on the client. Writing a form data encoder yourself may be useful if you really want to learn every little detail about how forms work. However, for most applications, I would not recommend it. The `FormData` API should be used in production.

You will need to refer to [RFC 7578](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7578) for how to implement the encoder.

> This specification defines the multipart/form-data media type, which can be used by a wide variety of applications and transported by a wide variety of protocols as a way of returning a set of values as the result of a user filling out a form.

More resources:

- [Meaning of multipart/form-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean)
- [Source code for the `form-data` library on npm](https://github.com/form-data/form-data/blob/master/lib/form_data.js)

Comment: I have a big nested json payload I post, and inside them one is file. It means I need to write create the form data object manually for each field?

Comment: No, you would most likely want just one `FormData` instance. You then need to decide which fields to put inside of that object using the `formData.append()` method. I would suggest having one field for the file and a second field for the JSON, which I assume is the file's metadata.

Comment: @SethHolladay can you give me example. I also have big nested json payload and suddently i got new feature that one is file Upload. i am using axios and i dont want to  create the form data object manually for each field